# Karma coverage reports show all files with 100% and require statements

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, karma-runner, code-coverage, browserify

I am generating coverage using karma-coverage, browserify. The tests run fine but the coverage reports generated are not showing correct file contents and shows 100% coverage when in reality there are tests for just few.

My karma.conf.js is :

```
    // Karma configuration

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: './',


        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['browserify', 'mocha', 'chai'],


        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
            'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
            'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
            'bower_components/angular-dragdrop/src/angular-dragdrop.js',
            'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
            'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
            'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
            'bower_components/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.js',
            'bower_components/d3/d3.js',
            'bower_components/d3-tip/index.js',
            'bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
            'bower_components/moment/moment.js',
            'bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.js',
            'bower_components/ngstorage/ngstorage.js',
            'bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js',
            'bower_components/toastr/toastr.js',
            'bower_components/underscore/underscore.js',
            'app/components/**/*.js'
        ],


        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [],


        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: {
            'app/components/**/*.js': ['browserify'],
            'app/components/**/!(*.test).js': ['browserify', 'sourcemap', 'coverage']
        },

        browserify: {
            debug: true,
            transform: [
                'babelify'
            ],
            extensions: ['.js']
        },

        babelPreprocessor: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: 'inline',
                blacklist: ['useStrict']
            },
            sourceFileName: function(file) {
                return file.originalPath;
            }
        },

        // optionally, configure the reporter
        coverageReporter: {
            dir: 'coverage/',
            reporters: [{
                type: 'html',
                subdir: 'report-html'
            }, {
                type: 'cobertura',
                subdir: '.',
                file: 'cobertura.txt'
            }, {
                type: 'text',
                subdir: '.',
                file: 'text.txt'
            }, {
                type: 'text-summary',
                subdir: '.',
                file: 'text-summary.txt'
            }, ]
        },


        // test results reporter to use
        // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
        // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
        reporters: ['coverage', 'mocha'],

        // web server port
        port: 9876,

        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,

        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,

        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        browsers: ['Chrome'],

        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: false
    });
};
```

and this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Touchpoint",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "repository": "",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "mocha": "istanbul cover _mocha -- ./app/components/**/*test.js --compilers js:babel-core/register",
    "watch-mocha": "istanbul cover _mocha -- ./app/components/**/*test.js --compilers js:babel-core/register -w",
    "karma": "karma start",
    "test": "npm run karma --single-run",
    "test-suite": "npm run watch-mocha",
    "pretest": "npm install",
    "pretest-suite": "npm install"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.0-rc.2",
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-cli": "6.10.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "bower": "^1.7.9",
    "browserify": "^13.0.1",
    "browserify-istanbul": "^2.0.0",
    "browserify-ngannotate": "^2.0.0",
    "bulkify": "^1.4.2",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^9.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.8.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^1.4.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
    "event-stream": "^3.3.2",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-angular-filesort": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.10",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-htmlhint": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-htmllint": "0.0.8",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-inject": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-inject-reload": "0.0.2",
    "gulp-install": "^0.6.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-ng-config": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-ng-html2js": "^0.2.2",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-open": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-order": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-postcss": "^6.1.1",
    "gulp-print": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-stylelint": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "istanbul": "^0.2.16",
    "istanbul-coveralls": "^1.0.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^2.1.0",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-babel-preprocessor": "^6.0.1",
    "karma-browserify": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.2.6",
    "karma-coverage-es6": "^0.2.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jquery": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-requirejs": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^1.2.3",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "main-bower-files": "^2.11.1",
    "method-override": "^2.3.5",
    "mocha": "^3.0.2",
    "postcss-nested": "^1.0.0",
    "postcss-reporter": "^1.3.3",
    "postcss-scss": "^0.1.8",
    "protractor": "^3.1.1",
    "q": "^1.4.1",
    "requirejs": "^2.2.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.6.0",
    "sinon": "^1.17.5",
    "stylelint": "^6.7.1",
    "stylelint-scss": "^1.2.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.7.0"
  }
}
```

I use npm run karma to run the tests.

I am using angular1.5 and my source files are in es6 standard with component style. I am also using import/export format.

What I get in coverage is all source files in green (100% coverage) and each file in the report is of the form:

> typeof require === "function" &&
>   require("**************************.js");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve a similar problem by using [browserify-istanbul](https://github.com/devongovett/browserify-istanbul) to instrument my code with a browserify [transform function](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#btransformtr-opts), rather than using the karma-coverage preprocessor.

1. Add browserify-istanbul as a dev dependency: `npm install browserify-istanbul --save-dev`
2. Add a browserify-istanbul to the browserify transform section of your karma.conf.js:

   ```
   transform: [
       'babelify',
       ['browserify-istanbul',
        {
            instrumenterConfig: {
                embedSource: true   // this is important for HTML reports
            }
        }
       ]
   ]
   ```
3. Remove `coverage` from your source preprocessors, so it's just:

   ```
   preprocessors: {
       'app/components/**/*.js': ['browserify'],
       'app/components/**/!(*.test).js': ['browserify', 'sourcemap']  // no more 'coverage' here
   }
   ```

Now, when karma runs the browserify preprocessor, the code will be instrumented by istanbul (because of the transform function), and the coverage report should look correct.

Comment: Worked great also for karma + webpack project! Thanks

Comment: It almost works for me... I do have the coverage but it is the transpiled code. What am I missing to show ES6 code in html coverage report ?

Comment: It worked for me using karma-remap-coverage ! Thanks